# when the text in first line out of margins is，how to manually make next line out of margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, margins, geometry, marginpar

This question is a bit strange, I want to show you the picture...
[image]

The fist line of text is out of margins, and I want to manually make the third line also out of margins, then the first line and third line can be aligned at both ends. Look like this:
[image]

Can someone help me?

MWE for test:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
left=30mm,
right=20mm,
top=40mm,
footskip=12mm,
bottom=35mm,
showframe
]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
    {\Large\sffamily
        ni dee Sitduietnrhcuhn
        etikhetonreEgcmal rahgkicrtelit und rhecn iquchnztk \\[1.5ex]

        na red afOlista  urf wdagentean sinschafseWten
        uohecHhlsc n/WraulBcihwofnbugtteseel
    }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using minipage:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
left=30mm,
right=20mm,
top=40mm,
footskip=12mm,
bottom=35mm,
showframe
]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
    {\Large\sffamily
        ni dee Sitduietnrhcuhn
        etikhetonreEgcmal rahgkicrtelit und rhecn iquchnztk \\[1.5ex]

        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth + 11pt}
        na red afOlista  urf wdagentean sinschafseWten
        uohecHhlsc n/WraulBcihwofnbugtteseel
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the text width or, as here, make the text fit in the specified width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
left=30mm,
right=20mm,
top=40mm,
footskip=12mm,
bottom=35mm,
showframe
]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
    {\Large\sffamily\sloppy\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
        ni dee Sitduietnrhcuhn
        etikhetonreEgcmal rahgkicrtelit und rhecn iquchnztk %no!\\[1.5ex]

        na red afOlista  urf wdagentean sinschafseWten
        uohecHhlsc n/WraulBcihwofnbugtteseel

% you need a blank line here
    }
\end{document}
```

I also removed the `\\` that was generating underfull box warnings (never use `\\` at the end of a paragraph)

Comment: thanks for your help, but in some times, increasing space between word looks like not so good, for example in titlepage, I have solved my problem by using minipage